# null hypothesis always rejected with large sample

Tags: hypothesis-testing, large-data

I'm doing hypotesis testing for my model in multiple linear regression with big data. Let say i have 1GB of data, 70% for training and 30% for testing. The result is null hypothesis always rejected,I know large sample would cause type 1 error in hypothesis testing. So, is it not appropiate to use hypothesis testing for big data?

Comment: I wouldn't say large sample sizes to generally cause an increase in type-I errors, but rather, that the more samples there are, the more subtle differences can be detected by hypothesis tests.

In other words, the more samples you have the more you need to be aware of the (sometimes implicit) subtle assumptions in your null hypotheses

Comment: So is it still meaningful to do hypothesis on big data? in my case i use f-statistic.

Comment: The more general question would be, what it is that you want to show. You may also formulate a larger set of null hypotheses, which increases your confidence in your results not being an effect of randomness, since you then have tested a variety of stochastic models, not just one. As in this case you also have to compensate for the multiple comparisons problem (e.g. by Bonferroni correction), it becomes harder to refute the hypotheses